# Подключиться к mssql 2005 через Android app

Tags: android, sql, sql-server

мой код

```
public class ConnectionClass {
    String ip = "192.168.1.212:2005";
    String classs = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    String db = "rbelz";
    String un = "neka";
    String password = "neka123";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection CONN() {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection conn = null;
        String ConnURL = null;
        try {

            Class.forName(classs);
            ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + "/"
                    + "databaseName=" + db + ";encrypt=fasle" + ";user=" + un + ";password="
                    + password + ";";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        }
        return conn;
    }
}
```

когда пытаюсь подключиться он мне выдает ошибку

E/ERRO: I/O Error: Unknown packet type 0x31

Как исправить ?

TCP/ip  открыл 
порт 2005

Comment: либа подключена?

Answer (score 0):

Работа с JDBC на Android сопряжена рядом проблем и в целом [не рекомендуется](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12233178/3100967). Хотя [официальная документация говорит, что это возможно](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/DriverManager.html), но советует использовать [`DataSource`](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/sql/DataSource.html).

В Вашем случае, скорее всего, драйвер, используемый приложением, несовместим с JDBC драйвером на сервере (схожая проблема, но для MySQL, вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304406/java-app-connecting-to-mysql-db-unknown-packet-type-0x4a)).

Судя по всему, проблема лечится только с помощью "подбора" рабочей версии JDBC драйвера для сервера. Как минимум, к MySQL подключиться [иногда удаётся](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6578235/3100967).